# one way direction, sails and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo, database

I have a question. I think i am doing something wrong.

I have two models: 
tutorType and Student.

Here is my Student

```
    module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    tutor1Name:'string',
    tutor1Type: {
        model: 'tutorType'
    },
    contact: {
        type: 'numeric'
    },

  }
};
```

And here is my TutorType

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    libelle: "string"
  }
};
```

I use the predefined blue print to insert. When i Insert a new student 
I have the returned response:

```
{
  "name": "Luke",
  "tutor1Type": "Biological",
  "createdAt": "2015-07-13T17:57:12.526Z",
  "updatedAt": "2015-07-13T17:57:12.526Z",
  "id": "55a3fbf8c9e93bf0266a63a8"
}
```

Should tutor1Type be an object instead of a String? Actually, I can put the string I want. I would like to be able to put only rows i have in TutorType with a foreign key on my Student.

What wrong I do?!

**EDIT**

Just add a look in my DB.
When I send the ID of the tutorType to my controller. It add an "Object(hashID)" in db. I presume that is a good news.

The things is that I can also insert string that are not into my tutorList...
I do not understand how integrity work right here...

Any ideas?!

Comment: Sund like you should have a field of `tutorType` that is an array with each row being an object of `_id` which relates to a tutor and the string which describes the type

Comment: If you just need a string for `tutor1Type` you can just use `enum`: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes
If you really need a separated model, then you have to use `.add()` and `.save()` methods: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values/add

Comment: Thanks for those answer. But the doc say that I don't need to do that: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-way-association .